# How to remove first part of string so I can decode it. flutter/dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting bytes property from api as a string but it has prefix and it looks like this:
`data:application/octet-stream;base64,JVBERi0xLjcNJeLjz9MNCjEgMCBvYmoNPDwv...`. So my question is how can i remove this part `data:application/octet-stream;base64,` from string so I can decode the rest of same string.

Comment: If the length of the prefix are always the same, you can look into `substring()`: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.6/dart-core/String/substring.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do it is like:

```
final str = "data:application/octet-stream;base64,JVBERi0xLjcNJeLjz9MNCjEgMCBvYmoNPDwv0w";
final desiredStr = str.substring(str.indexOf(',') + 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the built-in [`UriData` class](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/UriData-class.html) to parse data URLs *and* to automatically perform base64-decoding for you:

```dart
var dataUrl = 'data:application/octet-stream;base64,JVBERi0xLjcNJeLjz9MNCjEgMCBvYmoNPDwv...';
var parsedBytes = UriData.parse(dataUrl).contentAsBytes();
```

or a complete working example:

```dart
void main() {
  var dataUrl = Uri.dataFromBytes(
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    mimeType: 'application/octet-stream',
  ).toString();

  print(dataUrl); // Prints: data:application/octet-stream;base64,AAECAwQF
  
  var parsedBytes = UriData.parse(dataUrl).contentAsBytes();
  print(parsedBytes); // Prints: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use a `.split()` method.

```
  final str = "data:application/octet-stream;base64,JVBERi0xLjcNJeLjz9MNCjEgMCBvYmoNPDwv0w";
  final desiredStr = str.split(',')[1];
```

Comment: Note though, that if the part after the first comma also can contain commas this might not give the desired result

Comment: It seems like a static string, though yeah - it is definitely a good point.

Comment: It is enough for base64, base64 encoding doesn't include comma.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is Like :

```
final secondHalf = str!.split(',').last; /// Answer : JVBERi0xLjcNJeLjz9MNCjEgMCBvYmoNPDwv0w

final firstHald = str!.split(',').first;  /// Answer : data:application/octet-stream;base64
```

Answer (score 0):

I think data:application/octet-stream;base64, is base64 string of your any picture so simply you can use split method with split("data:application/octet-stream;base64,") so it will cut down the string in two part and i had a experience with bas64 string data:application/octet-stream;base64, is same every time so you can hard code it use use it like

`final str = "data:application/octet-stream;base64,JVBERi0xLjcNJeLjz9MNCjEgMCBvYmoNPDwv0w".split("data:application/octet-stream;base64,")[1];`